# Create A hMatrix View using single SQL query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: `tblEmpData`, `tblEmpAttDevice` and `tblEmpAttDeviceUsers`.

`tblEmpData` has all the employees, `tblEmpAttDevice` has all attendance devices and `tblEmpAttDeviceUsers` has employees attendance for specific device id.

Table schema:

**tblEmpData**:

```
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [EmpCivilID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EmpCivilIDExp] [date] NULL,
    [EmpHourWageKD] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [EmpPhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmpDOB] [date] NULL,
    [EmpJoinDate] [date] NULL,
    [EmpType] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [EmpEmail] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EmpAddress] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EmpPassword] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [EmpEnabled] [int] NULL,
    [EmpDeviceID] [int] NULL,
    [EmpCompanyHired] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [EmpVenueID] [int] NULL,
    [EmpStatusID] [int] NULL,
    [DriversLicenseNo] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DriversLicenseExpiry] [date] NULL
```

**tblEmpAttDevice**:

```
    [DeviceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeviceName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DeviceIP] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DevicePort] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VenueID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastImport] [datetime] NULL,
    [ACTIVE_FLAG] [bit] NULL
```

**tblEmpAttDeviceUsers**:

```
    [EmpID] [int] NULL,
    [DeviceID] [int] NULL,
    [lastseen] [datetime] NULL,
    [action] [int] NULL
```

I want to build SQL query to generate the following view.

[image]

All rows of `tblEmpAttDevice` table become columns and create matrix if any employee id exists in `tblEmpAttDeviceUsers` then Y else N.

I am in blocking stage how can I do this. Please help me to build a query in SQL Server. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  **PIVOT** in this situation.

Try with the below script.

```
SELECT EmpID,EmpName,Emp_Enabled,Employment_status
   ,CASE WHEN [Kuwait Soft]>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Kuwait Soft]
   ,CASE WHEN [Avenues]>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Avenues]
   ,CASE WHEN[360 Mall]>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [360 Mall]
   ,CASE WHEN [AlHarma]>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [AlHarma]
   ,CASE WHEN [Sidra]>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Sidra]
   ,CASE WHEN[Symphony]>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Symphony]

FROM
(SELECT a.EmpID, a.EmpID EmployeeID,a.EmpName
       ,a.EmpEnabled Emp_Enabled,a.EmpStatusID Employment_status,c.DeviceName
FROM tblEmpData a
 JOIN tblEmpAttDeviceUsers b on a.EmpID=b.EmpID
 JOIN tblEmpAttDevice c on b.DeviceID=c.DeviceID) src
 PIVOT (MAX([EmployeeID]) for [DeviceName]  IN ([Kuwait Soft],[Avenues],[360 Mall],[AlHarma],[Sidra],[Symphony]))as Res;
```

Output :

[image]